# Finding Elements by Attributes in a DOM Document

Tags: java, xml, dom

How to find elements by attributes in a DOM document with Java? Thanks.

Comment: shows absolutely no research effort

Comment: This is completely obvious, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a utility like [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/), you can wrap your DOM document and use a jQuery-like API to achieve what you need. You have several options:

- Using XPath (of course, instead of using jOOX, you could use the standard Java XPath API directly)

  ```
  Match match = $(document).xpath("//element[@attrName='value']");
  ```
- Using CSS-style selectors

  ```
  Match match = $(document).find("element[attrName='value']");
  ```
- Using the jOOX API

  ```
  Match match = $(document).find("element").filter(attr("attrName", "value"));
  ```

The returned `org.joox.Match` object can then be used in various ways, e.g. for iteration:

```
for (Element element : match.each()) {
  System.out.println($(element));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the options are as far as the XML/DOM parsing in Java, and I don't know what (if anything) you're using currently, but, if you have some way of finding elements via CSS selectors (a common feature in js frameworks), then CSS [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) would be the way to go.

Google turned [this](https://github.com/chrsan/css-selectors) Java implementation of CSS selectors up, perhaps it'll help.

Comment: I need to parse an XML document using Java.